# Javascript Sticky Element onscroll avoid jumping

Tags: javascript, fixed, onscroll

I'm trying to fix an element when I scroll down.
The code works fine but as you can see at the following [link](https://www.bva-doxa.com/fmcg/), the bar with the 3 yellow buttons jumps when it is about to reach the Top!
There seems to be some template css class causing this problem,
but I can't figure out which one

This is the code

```
var fixmeTop = $('.pulsanti').offset().top;       

$(window).scroll(function() {                  

    var currentScroll = $(window).scrollTop(); 

    if (currentScroll >= fixmeTop) {          
        $('.pulsanti').css({                      
            position: 'fixed',
            top: '0',
            zIndex: '1020'
        });
    } else {                                   
        $('.pulsanti').css({              
            position: 'relative'
        });
    }

});
```

thank you everyone

Comment: Well the code where you change position : relative (buttons stays where they are) to position : fixed is causing problem, that is why buttons jump up. If you put relative for position they will come back in old position.

Comment: @MirkoAcimovic sorry but I want the element to have the fixed position when I scroll!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that **fixmeTop** is assigned before some elements are loaded:

```
var fixmeTop = $('.pulsanti').offset().top;
```

My chrome console outputs this:

```
> fixmeTop 
< 2314.3374633789062
> $('.pulsanti').offset().top; 
< 3207.5623779296875
```

You can see that the **fixmeTop** variable is not the real element position.

Maybe you need to assign it in `body.onload()`?

**Update**

After executing `fixmeTop = $('.pulsanti').offset().top;` in the chrome console after the page is loaded, I can verify that the element is sticking smoothly to the top of the page.

Adding this code fragment will create a handler function to be called when the window's load event fires. That will happen after everything (divs, images) is loaded. This way the **fixmeTop** will contain the true element position.

```
window.onload = function () {
   fixmeTop = $('.pulsanti').offset().top;
}
```

You can keep the variable declaration in the original script, or remove it and add `var` here.

Also, bear in mind that **it will not work until everything on the page is loaded and that it will not be valid when anything on the page moves** - eg. page resize, divs rearranged. You would have to add listeners for every such event to adjust the value accordingly. Something like this may be useful:

```
function updateFixmeTop() {
    fixmeTop = $('.pulsanti').offset().top;
}

window.addEventListener("resize", updateFixmeTop);
```

*edit: changed element body to window in event listener*

Hope it helps!

**Update2**

Let's say you added the code for **resize event listener** and scrolled past the point where the element should stick to the top. If you were to resize window **fixmeTop** would be assigned a value that corresponds to the element being on top of the page, and not the original element position.

To fix this you may want to add a dummy element without any margin or padding:

```
<div id="elementJustBeforeFixmeTop"></div> <! -- dummy element -->
<div class="pulsanti"> <! -- sticky element -->
    ...
</div>
```

And refer to its position instead of the sticky element

```
fixmeTop = $('#elementJustBeforeFixmeTop').offset().top;
```

This way you will store the scroll position at which you want the element to stick and it will not be different if the element is already at the top.

You may want to check if your page doesn't change its layout somewhere else and also update the *fixmeTop* value there to ensure it's always pointing at the right element.

Comment: i don't think i have to change code...as you can see on this duplicate page i have delete all element before button yellow and the bar fix well [link](https://www.bva-doxa.com/fmcg-3-2/)

Comment: In this example, the values are the same so it works as expected.
On your page, you linked in question the values don't match.
```
> $('.pulsanti').offset().top; 
< 350
> fixmeTop 
< 350
```

Comment: Your code evaluates **if (currentScroll >= fixmeTop)** but the **fixmeTop** is set to some value that does not correspond with the real position of the element

Comment: ok , how can fix the code ? with body.onload() ?

Comment: move the **var fixmeTop = $('.pulsanti').offset().top;** to someplace after the page is loaded. I will update the answer later.

Comment: thank you very much, if adding the code snippet the button bar fixes well ... adding this code `body.addEventListener (" resize ", updateFixmeTop);` I get the error body undefined ... so I add `$ ('body ') .addEventListener` to resolve the error but if I resize the browser window from top to bottom the button bar doesn't fix properly!

Comment: yea, my bad. resize should be bound to **window** not body. Also I can tell you that simply assigning value on resize will not fix the issue entirely. If you trigger this event when the element is already sticky to the top it will assign its current position - the scroll position - to **fixmeTop** . you may fi it by creating a dummy element just before the real element and record it's position. I will again update my answer

Comment: Thank you...i think now is working fine [link](https://www.bva-doxa.com/fmcg/)...I just have to eliminate the jump that the block under the yellow button bar makes when it fixes ... I think it is a padding or margin problem

Comment: you can do something like changing the dummy element padding-bottom to the height of the sticky element when the element sticks